# how to get a url to directly download a github release?

Tags: github, download, release, github-pages

I created a github webpage recently which I attached to a github repository. Is there a way to put a link on that webpage to download a specific file (big one that I couldn't put directly on the repository) I uploaded as a release on github?

Comment: All files attached to releases are available by theirs links. Like: https://github.com/User/Repo/archive/somefile.zip You can find it in https://github.com/User/Repo/releases page. Clarify what exactly link do you need?

Comment: @OlegPro I want to get a link to put inside the html file (of a github webpage) so that people that click on this link on the webpage get to directly download the file instead of getting redirected to the release page. Also do you know why people down voted the question, i'm new in this stack and don't understand its policies yet!

Comment: I think you downvoted because you don't give specifics about your question. Give your code example, explain how it behaves and what the expected behavior. What is your question different from "just put a link to the site to download the file"

Comment: Just an example: ```<div>
          download the
          <a href="https://github.com/sm-react/react-theming/releases/download/0.2.0/storybook-boilerplate-project.zip"> latest release</a>
        </div>``` - You can put everwhere and it will work: `"directly download the file instead of getting redirected to the release page"`. If it's not an answer for your question, please, give me more details about what do you need

Comment: @OlegPro It answered my question. I'm new to html and github that's why something so easy caused me trouble. thanks!

Comment: glad to hear it. If it helps you, could you accept my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an example:

```
<div> download the 
  <a href="https://github.com/sm-react/react-theming/releases/donload/0.2.0/storybok-boilerplate-projet.zip"> latest release</a>       

</div>
```